# SaltStack - generate pillar value base on what folder it is being executed

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to learn SaltStack and now I'm facing a problem.
I have a property file (propertyfile.properties) with values being populated by salt pillar. Now this property file exists in multiple directories. The issue that I have is that I want the values of the property file be populated/rendered by salt pillar.get function base on what directory currently it is into. To give you more idea, let's consider this example:

```
propertyfile.property (in directory 1)
name={{ salt['pillar.get']['dir1.name'] }}


propertyfile.property (in directory 2)
name={{ salt['pillar.get']['dir2.name'] }}

#pillar
dir1.name=dir1
dir2.name=dir2
```

note that the property file is only one and is generated by salt to multiple directories via loop like this:

```
{% for dir in 'dir1', 'dir2' %}
propertyfile_properties_{{ dir }}:
    file.managed:
        - name: /home/devuser/{{ dir }}/propertyfile.properties
        - source: {{ propertyfile_source }}
        - source_hash: {{ propertyfile_source }}.MD5
        - template: jinja
        - show_diff: True
        - makedirs: True
{% endfor %}
```

Any ideas? Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This may not be off-topic here, but it would probably be better on Server Fault.

Comment: I see. Thanks @chrylis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by passing each directory to the template as context, as it's rendered:

```
# In .sls
{% for dir in salt['pillar.get']("directories") %}
propertyfile_properties_{{ dir }}:
    file.managed:
        - name: /home/devuser/{{ dir }}/propertyfile.properties
        - source: salt://path/to/template.jinja
        - template: jinja
        - context:
            dir: {{ dir }}
{% endfor %}

# In template:
dirname={{ dir }}
fullpath=/home/devuser/{{ dir }}/propertyfile.properties

# In pillar:
directories:
  - dir1
  - dir2
  - ...and so on
```

Note the extra indentation of the contents of the `context` dictionary. There's an explanation of why that's sometimes necessary [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/troubleshooting/yaml_idiosyncrasies.html#nested-dictionaries).

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, that did the job. Also, can i ask another question? How can i get a dynamic value from loop when executing salt['pillar.get']? Is it something like this? 

{% for a in 'a','b' %}
salt['pillar.get']('test_{{ a }}')
{% endfor %}

Comment: To answer my last question, all i did was to remove {{}} inside a and replace it with '+ a +' since a is already inside {{ salt['pillar.get'] }}

Comment: Hi @Andrew, i'm successful in getting the current dir via the context. However, this does not work: dirname={{ dir }} ## this result to dir1 name={{ salt['pillar.get'](dirname +'.name','default_name') }} it always get the default_name value whereas my dir1.name has a value of 'new_name'. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be (dir + '.name')? Might be better to open a new question if it's not that simple.